# Counting different number of combinations that exists in a column

Tags: pandas, combinations

I have DNA sequences of different bacterias with different lengths that are in string format. Example:

```
DNA
xx345- b324- c82- d13- c14
xx345- a22- c14- d13
a34- f12 - r27- fg98 - tr12
z23
xx345
```

I would like to count co-occurrences of each DNA piece in my data set. I need two outputs. First:

```
pair          
xx345- b324     
xx345- c82     
xx345- d13      
xx345- a22      
xx345- c14      
xx345- c14      
b324- c82       
b324- d13       
b324- c14       
c82- d13        
c82- c14        
d13- c14        
d13- c14        
a22- c14        
a22- d13        
a34- f12        
a34- r27        
a34- fg98       
a34- tr12       
f12- r27        
f12- fg98       
f12- tr12       
r27- fg98       
r27- tr12       
fg98- tr12   
z23   
xx345
```

Then

```
pair          count
xx345- b324     1
xx345- c82      1
xx345- d13      1
xx345- a22      1
xx345- c14      2
b324- c82       1
b324- d13       1
b324- c14       1
c82- d13        1
c82- c14        1
d13- c14        2
a22- c14        1
a22- d13        1
a34- f12        1
a34- r27        1
a34- fg98       1
a34- tr12       1
f12- r27        1
f12- fg98       1
f12- tr12       1
r27- fg98       1
r27- tr12       1
fg98- tr12      1
z23             1
xx345           1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need split values by `\s*-\s*` - here `\s*` means zero or more spaces, then flatten in list comprehension all combinations:

```
from  itertools import combinations

L = ['-'.join(y) for x in df['DNA'].str.split('\s*-\s*') for y in combinations(x, 2)]
```

If necessary sorting values:

```
L = ['-'.join(sorted(y)) for x in df['DNA'].str.split('\s*-\s*') 
     for y in combinations(x, 2)]
```

Last pass to `Series` and call [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
s = pd.Series(L)
print (s)
0     xx345-b324
1      xx345-c82
2      xx345-d13
3      xx345-c14
4       b324-c82
5       b324-d13
6       b324-c14
7        c82-d13
8        c82-c14
9        d13-c14
10     xx345-a22
11     xx345-c14
12     xx345-d13
13       a22-c14
14       a22-d13
15       c14-d13
16       a34-f12
17       a34-r27
18      a34-fg98
19      a34-tr12
20       f12-r27
21      f12-fg98
22      f12-tr12
23      r27-fg98
24      r27-tr12
25     fg98-tr12
dtype: object
```

---

```
s1 = s.value_counts()
print (s1)
xx345-c14     2
xx345-d13     2
c14-d13       1
f12-tr12      1
xx345-a22     1
a34-fg98      1
f12-r27       1
a34-r27       1
c82-c14       1
f12-fg98      1
a22-c14       1
a34-tr12      1
a34-f12       1
b324-d13      1
r27-tr12      1
xx345-c82     1
d13-c14       1
b324-c14      1
xx345-b324    1
r27-fg98      1
fg98-tr12     1
b324-c82      1
c82-d13       1
a22-d13       1
dtype: int64
```

EDIT:

```
from  itertools import combinations

L = []
for x in df['DNA'].str.split('\s*-\s*'):
    if len(x) > 1:
        for y in combinations(x, 2):
            L.append('-'.join(sorted(y)))
    else:
        L.append(x[0])


s = pd.Series(L)
print (s)
```

Comment: Sorry, there are also viruses with single element, do you mind if I update the question?